# LINQ to SQL INSERT Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I am experiencing a very frustrating issue when trying to insert a new record 
using LINQ to SQL. If I step through this code sometimes it inserts the new record
but most of the time it doesn't. When it fails I seeing the following error.

> Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'Name', table
>   'EquipmentManufacturer'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

This error is complaining about the 'Name' field being null but that should not be the case. When I debug and step through this collection["Name"] has the value I entered on the form.

Here is the table create statement.

```
CREATE TABLE [EquipmentManufacturer] (
  [EquipmentManufacturerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_EquipmentManufacturer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [EquipmentManufacturerID] ASC
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the ASP.NET MVC Controller and Create Action where I am trying to add a new record.

```
public partial class EquipmentManufacturerController : Controller
{
  private IRepository<EquipmentManufacturer> reposManu;

  // POST: /EquipmentManufacturer/Create
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
  public virtual ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
  {
    EquipmentManufacturer entity = reposManu.New();
    try
    {
      //HACK: Something screwy is going on here the entity oject doesn't always get updated correctly
      //UpdateModel(entity);

      entity.Name = collection["Name"];
      reposManu.Insert(entity);
      reposManu.SubmitChanges();

      return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = entity.EquipmentManufacturerID });
    }
    catch (RulesException ex)
    {
      ex.AddModelStateErrors(ModelState, "EquipmentManufacturer");
      return ModelState.IsValid ? RedirectToAction("Create")
        : (ActionResult)View();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Create.aspx view.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Create</h2>

    <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Create was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Fields</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="Name">Name:</label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Name") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name") %>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>

    <% } %>
    <%= Html.ClientSideValidation<EquipmentManufacturer>() %>

    <div>
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Here is the Repository implementation I am using.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
  public IDataContext DC { get; set; }

  public Repository(IDataContext dataContext)
  {
      DC = dataContext;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Return all instances of type T.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public IEnumerable<T> All()
  {
      return GetTable;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Return all instances of type T that match the expression exp.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="exp"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public IQueryable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
  {
      return GetTable.Where<T>(exp);
  }

  /// <summary>See IRepository</summary>
  /// <param name="exp"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public T Single(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
  {
      return GetTable.SingleOrDefault(exp);
  }

  /// <summary>See IRepository</summary>
  /// <param name="exp"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
  {
      return GetTable.First(exp);
  }

  /// <summary>See IRepository</summary>
  /// <param name="entity"></param>
  public virtual void Delete(T entity)
  {
      DC.Context.GetTable<T>().DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Create a new instance of type T.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public virtual T New()
  {
      T entity = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
      GetTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
      return entity;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Adds an insance T.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public virtual void Insert(T entity)
  {
      GetTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Update entity.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public virtual void Update(T entity)
  {
      DC.Context.Refresh(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, entity);
  }

  /// <summary>See IRepository</summary>
  public void SubmitChanges()
  {
      DC.SubmitChanges();
  }

  private string PrimaryKeyName
  {
      get { return TableMetadata.RowType.IdentityMembers[0].Name; }
  }

  private System.Data.Linq.Table<T> GetTable
  {
      get { return DC.Context.GetTable<T>(); }
  }

  private System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable TableMetadata
  {
      get { return DC.Context.Mapping.GetTable(typeof(T)); }
  }

  private System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaType ClassMetadata
  {
      get { return DC.Context.Mapping.GetMetaType(typeof(T)); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it because you are calling .InsertOnSubmit(entity) twice?

You call it once in New()

```
public virtual T New()
{
    T entity = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    GetTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

And then again in .Insert()

```
public virtual void Insert(T entity)
{
    GetTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
}
```

Personally I would remove the GetTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity) from the New() method.

Reason being that I think it would be better for the user of the repository to specifically insert the entity rather than it automatically get set for insertion every single time they create a new one.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: This does seem to resolve my issue, however I am not quite sure why. If I comment out the GetTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity) from the Repository New method it works. If I leave the InsertOnSubmit call in the Repository New method and comment out the reposManu.Insert(entity) call in the controller it fails.

Comment: Judging by what you've just said, it makes sense that when you are calling .InsertOnSubmit(entity) it takes a copy of the object to save it. So when you call .InsertOnSubmit on the brand spanking new EquipmentManufacturer it tries to insert a copy of it which contains no values, so therefore it'll fail against your database constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem because I had set the `Auto Generated Value` option in my *.dbml Ling2SQL file to `true`; I changed it to `false` and the error went away.  Its a simple mistake but it took me forever to find as I didn't intentionally set the value to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this sort of problem generally comes from errors in the mapping configuration.

Some suggestions for finding an answer:

- Use SQL Profiler to trace the INSERT statements, which might give you more clues.
- Double-check the mapping for the EquipmentManufacturer class, Name might not be mapped correctly. Include that information in your question as it provides a better picture of the problem.

Comment: I have used SQL Profiler and I see that the Name parameter passed in is null. I don't know what is happening though because on this line reposManu.Insert(entity) entity.Name isn't null.

Comment: Trace through what LINQ to SQL does when it retrieves the value to insert - there is obviously a mapping for the Name column as it is in the SQL, but have you checked that the mapping entry (attributes or XML) is actually pointing to the correct property / field on your entity class?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are not using the 'auto-bind' (or whatever you call it, where you accept the entity you want bound as the action method parameter) but are instead (A) newing the object and (B) setting its "Name" property from the formCollection manually. Perhaps I do not see where the "EquipmentManufacturerID" is being bound?

Is the NULL failure on this EquipmentManufacturerID property?

Comment: No its on the Name property. I have tried using a method signature like public virtual ActionResult Create([Bind()] EquipmentManufacturer) and I still have the same problem.

Comment: have you tried logging the underlying SQL that LTS is generating? If you could see what it was sending the server, it might help you debug this further...?